# Cannot find Spring's SSEmitter Event "name" property in the resulting event-stream value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey-2.0, server-sent-events

I'm using Server Sent Events (SSE) within the Spring Framework. I'm able to register to those streams with javascript code in the chrome browser and in the backend using **jersey-media-sse**

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem now is that Spring's SSEmitter logic is not setting the **name** attribute of the event as expected. Using the setter in the sending logic below seems intuitive - but the resulting value on the consuming/receiving client side yields **name:null**. The attribute still is available - but hard to find in one of three **data** fields of a big JSON String.

Please read the following to understand the issue in detail

---

**Here is a snippet of the Endpoint which should yield a SSEvent stream**

```
  @CrossOrigin(Resources.Origins.FRONTEND)
  @GetMapping(GET_LOG + "/stream")
  public SseEmitter subscribeToLogEventStream() {
    Optional<SseEmitter> sseEmitter = createAndSubscribe(EVENT_IDENTIFIER);
    return sseEmitter.orElse(null);
  }
```

**Here is the logic for sending an event**

```
 void sendEvent(SseEmitter sseEmitter, String toolId, String message) {
    SseEmitter.SseEventBuilder sseEventBuilder = SseEmitter.event()
            .data(message, MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
            .name(toolId);
    Set<ResponseBodyEmitter.DataWithMediaType> event = sseEventBuilder.build();

    try {
      sseEmitter.send(event);
      log.debug("Sending SSEvent");
    } catch (ClientAbortException e) {
      log.error("Stream connection is not longer established. Aborting.", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("Server sent event emitter failed", e);
    }

  }
```

**Receiving this event in the backend the InboundEvent object yields these properties**

[image]

Please note that the **name** field happens to be empty although it is set in the sending logic

```
 SseEmitter.SseEventBuilder sseEventBuilder = SseEmitter.event()
                .data(message, MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                .name(toolId);
```

Actually the **name** field is defined within the *3rd* data field of the following JSON String.

**The weirdly formatted event stream data**

```
    [
  {
    "data": "data:",
    "mediaType": {
      "type": "text",
      "subtype": "plain",
      "parameters": {
        "charset": "UTF-8"
      },
      "qualityValue": 1.0,
      "concrete": true,
      "wildcardType": false,
      "charSet": "UTF-8",
      "charset": "UTF-8",
      "wildcardSubtype": false
    }
  },
  {
    "data": "Wed Jan 24 18:17:13 CET 2018>ERROR: Finishing execution but still unhappy",
    "mediaType": {
      "type": "text",
      "subtype": "event-stream",
      "parameters": {},
      "qualityValue": 1.0,
      "concrete": true,
      "wildcardType": false,
      "charSet": null,
      "charset": null,
      "wildcardSubtype": false
    }
  },
  {
    "data": "\nevent:foo\n\n", // <<<< Name definition (suffixed with event)
    "mediaType": {
      "type": "text",
      "subtype": "plain",
      "parameters": {
        "charset": "UTF-8"
      },
      "qualityValue": 1.0,
      "concrete": true,
      "wildcardType": false,
      "charSet": "UTF-8",
      "charset": "UTF-8",
      "wildcardSubtype": false
    }
  }
]
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out that the `.send()` method does not expect an event created by the `SseEmitter.SseEventBuilder` - no it expects the builder itself. That was kinda not intuitive for me and therefore not realised for a long time.

```
 void sendEvent(SseEmitter sseEmitter, String toolId, String message) {
    SseEmitter.SseEventBuilder sseEventBuilder = SseEmitter.event()
            .data(message)
            .name(toolId);

    try {
      sseEmitter.send(sseEventBuilder );
      log.debug("Sending SSEvent");
    } catch (ClientAbortException e) {
      log.error("Stream connection is not longer established. Aborting.", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("Server sent event emitter failed", e);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Man you saved my life I was getting crazy! Thanks so much and tell me where should I send you a beer ;)